# Activerecord OR condition for a Joined table's attribute

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to write an query returning

- All tasks where a user_id = self.id
  OR
- all tasks whereby the associated trip's booker_id = self.id

  ```
  Task.joins(:trip).where('user_id = ? OR trip.booker_id = ?', self.id, self.id)
  ```

The above returns the error

```
  PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "user_id" is ambiguous
```

Any help / explanation would be appreciated

Comment: You have to specify the table for column user_id. So try `Tasks.user_id`. if you have two columns with the same title, it will be ambiguous for query planner as which table to choose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `user_id` column in your `trips` table, so PG doesn't know what you mean when you write `user_id = ...`. You need to specify table name, like here:

```
Task.joins(:trip).where('tasks.user_id = :id OR trip.booker_id = :id', id: self.id)
```